# How to clone a vector with struct items in it (rust)?

Tags: vector, rust, clone, traits

How to clone a vector with struct items in `Rust`.

I've tried to `.to_vec()` it, but it seems that I can't because I'm using structs.

```rust
struct Abc {
    id: u32,
    name: String
}

let mut vec1: Vec<Abc> = vec![];

let item1 = Abc {
    id: 1,
    name: String::from("AlgoQ")
}

vec1.push(item1)

let vec2 = vec1.to_vec();
```

Error:

```
the trait bound `blabla::Abc: Clone` is not satisfied
the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `blabla::Abc`rustc(E0277)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To clone a `Vec` the Type inside the `Vec` also has to implement the [Clone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) trait.
The easiest way to do this is to use the [derive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/derive.html) macro as seen [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#derivable).

In your example you'd just have to add `#[derive(Clone)]` above your `Abc` struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for objects of structs as you do it for primitives but the struct of the elements of the vector must implement `Clone` trait to make the vector cloneable.

Exactly as the compiler says

You can use `#[derive()]` `macro` easily to implement the `trait`, unless you don't want to use a custom implementation, as follows

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Abc {
    id: u32,
    name: String
}

fn main(){
    let mut vec1= vec![];

    let item1 = Abc {
        id: 1,
        name: String::from("AlgoQ"),
    };
    vec1.push(item1);

    let vec2 = vec1.clone();
    
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e329c4286915fc9517a7ba891d89c5f)